# Points on the interface

Tags: finite-difference, numerical-analysis, elliptic-pde

We consider the problem

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
k(x)\Delta u(x)=f(x) & \text{ in } \Omega\\ 
u=0 &  \text{ in } \Gamma
\end{matrix}\right.$

where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open and bounded with smooth boundary $\Gamma=\partial{\Omega}$ and $k(x) \geq a, \forall x \in \Omega$.

We consider that $\Omega= \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$ and that $k$ is always a constant $k(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
k_1 & \text{ in } \Omega_1 \\ 
k_2 & \text{ in } \Omega_2 
\end{matrix}\right.$

[image]

$\Sigma$ is the boundary between $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, $\Sigma= \overline{\Omega_1} \cap \overline{\Omega_2}, \Gamma_j=\Gamma \cap \partial{\Omega_j}, j=1,2$.

We suppose that $\Omega=[-1,1]^2$ and $\Sigma=[-1,1] \times \{ y=0 \}, \Omega_1=\Omega \cap \{ y>0 \}$ and $\Omega_2=\Omega \cap \{ y<0 \}$.

We construct a grid $\Omega$ so that the interface $\Sigma$ coincides with the sides of the squares.

[image]

We write the problem as $AU=f$ in order to find the approximation of the solution.

For the approximations that correspond to the points that are over $\Sigma$ we pick $k1$ and for the approximations that correspond to the points that are under $\Sigma$ we pick $k2$.

What do we do for the approimations that correspond to the points that are on $\Sigma$ ?

**EDIT**:Finally, we don't want the approximation of the solution to be continuous.
We may take $k=\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}$ for the points on the interface. So do we have to take cases for $y$ in order to give a value to $k$?

Comment: what physical problem do you considering?

Comment: Is your interface moving?

Comment: No, it's the line $y=0$. @nluigi

Comment: In that case perhaps my answer to [this](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5921/modeling-transient-heat-transfer-between-two-1-d-materials/5925#5925) question might be useful; specifically check out the section *Simulating a composite material*. It is based on a Finite Volume approach in which the interface is located halfway between nodes.

Comment: @nluigi Could you look at my question of the last comment if you have an idea?

Comment: @evinda Sorry which comment are you referring too?

Comment: @nluigi  
I calculated the error as follows: pastebin.com/apK9k5mP I get these error: pastebin.com/it7b67Ei Can these errors be correct? Why does the error increse for N=30? Do we calculate the order of accuracy as follows? pastebin.com/iq0cnYLP Then I get: pastebin.com/bxa19CLu Is this correct?

Comment: @nluigi Have you seen my comments below?

Comment: @nluigiI calculated the error with the following code: 


http://pastebin.com/RZ9D1See



and I get the following results: 

http://pastebin.com/rZEASC7r 


The error is not decreasing... Is something wrong at the code at which I calculate the error? Or maybe at some other pont for example at the code where I calculate the function f, which is the following? 


 http://pastebin.com/xY1Lfjcn 


where http://pastebin.com/j40J12Tw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your problem as
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u(x)=\frac{f(x)}{k_1}& \text{ in } \Omega_1\\ 
\Delta u(x)=\frac{f(x)}{k_2}& \text{ in } \Omega_2\\ 
u=0 &  \text{ in } \Gamma
\end{cases}$$
you have to add a condition on an interface, for example a jump condition, e.g.
$$u^1(x)-u^2(x)=\alpha(x)\quad\text{and}\quad 
u^1_n(x)-u^2_n(y)=\beta(x)
 ,\quad x\in\Sigma$$
 or smoothness (e.g. $\alpha=0=\beta$) of the solution and its normal derivative across the interface. In the above $u^i$ is the solution in the domain $\Omega_i$, $i\in\{1,2\}$.

One of the best ways to solve such problem would be [Difference Potentials Method](http://www.math.utah.edu/~mmedvin/Publications/MedvinskyPHDDissertation.pdf) (based on good theory, need time to learn, worth the time you spend on it), another is Immersed Interface method(easy to understand, implementation is involved and changes with the problem, less accurate). 
You find a little more under the link provided.

**Regularization approach**

If the low order of accuracy is enough for you, you may want to try something very simple. 
You take a [continuous approximation of step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and solve a little bit different, but continuous problem, e.g.:
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g_p(x)}& \text{ in } \Omega_1\cup \Omega_2\\ 
u=0 &  \text{ in } \Gamma
\end{cases}$$
where (you can choose another approximation of step function)
$$g_p=\frac{k_2-k_1}{1+e^{-M(x-p)}} + k_1.
$$
$M$ supposed to be a big number, the larger the $M$ the sharper the "jump", i.e. the closest to what you need. You can play with different values to see the effect.
Note, when $x<p$ the denominator is a big number and so the fraction become close to zero. when $x>p$ the exponential in the denominator is negligible  and therefore the fraction is almost the nominator.

Thus, this way you solve a problem without singularities or jumps. However, you solve a little bit different problem, which is asymptotically (as $M\to\infty$) tends to the original one.

Comment: What condition on an interface could we pick for example? That is the point where I am facing difficulties... $$$$
I have to use finite difference methods to find the approximation of the solution.

Comment: edited the post a little. the choice of interface condition depends on the problem. all the methods I've mentioned are based on FD.

Comment: Could you explain me why we can take the conditions you mentioned above for the points on the interface?

Comment: If you consider each sub-domain separately, you actually missing a condition on $\Sigma$. So it is not a question of "why can we take conditions", but a question of how do we make the problem well posed.

Comment: So if we take these conditions, will the solution of the problem with different $k1$ and $k2$ be continuous? How can we check this?

Comment: what physical problem do you consider behind these equations?
If the interface conditions are smoothness than your solution will be smooth, if the interface condition is a jump - then you will have a solution with jump. http://www.math.utah.edu/~mmedvin/Publications/Epshteyn_Medvinskyrevise1.pdf

Comment: It isn't given anything about the interface conditions. It is only given that $\Gamma=\partial{\Omega}$ is a smooth boundary and that the elliptic problem is about a static problem in a heterogeneous medium.
$$$$
So can we assume for example smoothness of the interface conditions so that the solution is smooth?

Comment: If so, what condition could we take?

Comment: depends on the underlying physical problem

Comment: Finally, we don't want the approximation of the solution to be continuous. $$$$
We may take $k=\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}$ for the points on the interface. So do we have to take cases for $y$ in order to give a value to $k$?

Comment: see the next edit in a while

Comment: I get that the order of accuracy -0.0048... but it should be 2. Could I show you my code of the calculation of the error so that you check if I have done somthing wrong?

Comment: if you use $k_1$ in $\Omega_1$, $k_2$ in $\Omega_2$ and $frac{k_1+k_2}2$ on $\Sigma$ then you tottaly lose the accuracy, which is pretty much what you have.

Comment: Could you explain me why?

Comment: because the singularity

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: when you use FD you assume continuity, but you have discontinuity. More, the error term of the numerical scheme is given in terms of the derivatives of the solution, when the derivatives aren't continuous or unbounded, the error may be huge and the convergence of the method cannot be expected.

Comment: When we have the exact solution and the approximation of the solution in a $N \times N$ matrix, how do we find the error? Can we use the command `norm(uexact-uapprox,inf)` ?

Comment: norm(uexact(:)-uapprox(:),inf)

Comment: I calculated the error as follows:  http://pastebin.com/apK9k5mP


I get these error: http://pastebin.com/it7b67Ei




Can these errors be correct? Why does  the error increse for N=30? 


Do we calculate the order of accuracy as follows? 

http://pastebin.com/iq0cnYLP

Then I get: http://pastebin.com/bxa19CLu


Is this correct?

Comment: not enough information to answer the question. From one side you get the error of machine zero, which is good, from the other side I don't know what you comparing there. The solution is defined on the rectangular grid, but you should compare them as vectors, this why the $(:)$ needed. From the other side, you send vectors as input to your exact solution, so I don't know what do you get back. Can you please edit your question and provide full information about the test case. Please also plot your exact and approx solutions with title, legend, and all required information.

Comment: We have the exact solution and the approximation in a $N \times N$ matrix. Why do we have to use $(:)$ and not $(:,:)$ ?

Comment: @evinda could you edit your question and post the code? It is difficult to say if it is correct. The error should decrease with decreasing grid spacing so increasing error for n=30 is strange.

Comment: @evinda because in the corresponding linear system the function is a vector - so you have to measure the error in a vector norm.

Comment: @nluigi he gets a machine zero. would it be correct (I guess not)  I would say the exact problem is too simple and what we see is a saturation.

Comment: @evinda $(:)$ returns all elements of the matrix as a vector. Taking the norm of a matrix is not  the same as taking the norm of a vector with the same elements as the vector. You want them as vector. Still it would be best if you could post the code and some results in your question so we can have a look.

Comment: You mean the code where I calculate the error? I calculated the error as follows: http://pastebin.com/apK9k5mP 
I get these error: http://pastebin.com/it7b67Ei

Comment: the code of uapprox, the function and/or the code of uexact, exact values of $k_1,k_2$ and $f(x,y)$

Comment: @evinda - all codes in one big pastebin! It seems you are not calculating the error correctly; you want $\epsilon=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N^{2}}
 \left(u_{e,i}-u_{a,i}\right)^2}$. In matlab you calculate that using `udif = uexact-uapprox; error=norm(udif(:));`. That properly calculates the 2-norm of all data points. `norm(uexact-uapprox,Inf)` calculates the largest singular value which is not the same. You can verify this: `A = magic(3); n = sqrt(sum(sum(A.^2))), n == norm(A(:)), n == norm(A,Inf), n==norm(A)` -> the first conditional returns `true`, the second and third conditional return `false`

Comment: The codes  of approx and uexact that I have written are the following: http://pastebin.com/acpNJj0U
$$$$
I use the values $k_1=k_2=1$ and the function $f(x,y)=2((x^2-1)+(y^2-1))$. 






When I use the command `udif = uexact-uapprox; error=norm(udif(:));` instead of `norm(uexact-uapprox,inf)` I get the following errors: 

http://pastebin.com/AgyvA9ST


The error for $N=30$ is again increasing.

Comment: ok, so you solve non singular problem.
I didn't look at all code, yet...but so far
please run your problem with N=2^n, n=1:10
test with 
Error(N)=norm(uapprox(:)-uexact(:),inf);
rate=log2(Error(1:end-1)/Error(2:end))
print the results...

please edit your question instead of comments - make it more readable....also don't delete old pastbin...

Comment: I changed the code as follows:  http://pastebin.com/HvKu2WQg

and I got the following results: http://pastebin.com/MCzqgE3S
$$$$
These results can't be correct... Can they?

Comment: please print the error and rate=order  also use 
"format long"

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky http://pastebin.com/dU9VtdAt

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky What could be wrong? I can't find the mistake..

Comment: please run again after the following changes and post

1) please change (`./` instead of `/`) in rate calculation, i.e.   
`rate=log2(Error(1:end-1)./Error(2:end))`

2) change your function to be `function [rate,Error]=order`

3) change the error calculation to be (note the small `n`, it shouldn't be the big one and also terminate the row with`;`!)

`Error(n)=norm(uapprox(:)-uexact(:),inf)/norm(uapprox(:),inf);`

Comment: I think that we finished with the original question and now discussing another question(debugging your code), which should be posted separately, with a link to this one if you need. Otherwise we do endless comments which are less convenient.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinskyI calculated the error with the following code: 


http://pastebin.com/RZ9D1See



and I get the following results: 

http://pastebin.com/rZEASC7r 


The error is not decreasing... Is something wrong at the code at which I calculate the error? Or maybe at some other pont for example at the code where I calculate the function f, which is the following? 


 http://pastebin.com/xY1Lfjcn 


where http://pastebin.com/j40J12Tw

Comment: please look at my previous comment and do what I asked.

Comment: also you may be interesting in meshgrid function.
if $x,y$ are vectors, e.g. $x_j=x_0 + jh$ then the corresponding grid is `[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y)`.  So what you need for RHS is  `fff(X,Y)`, where fff is your function from pastebing....

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Ok, I will do it in a bit... I used meshgrid but the error is still not decreasing...

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I have posted a new question: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21376/calculation-of-error

Comment: you missed one of my comments...where I ask you some changes of the code.....when you finish with it - please past the result to the new question

Comment: Do you mean that I should use this command? Error(n)=norm(uapprox(:)-uexact(:),inf)/norm(uapprox(:),inf);
$$$$
Doesn't this calculate the relative error? Or am I wrong? @MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: Yes, I asked you to show the relative error and to do few other changes

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Why do we calculate the relative error?

Comment: to test your program

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31970/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-medvinsky-points-on-the-interface).

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky What does it mean that the interface should coincide with the sides of the squares at the grid?

Comment: conform the grid?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky What do you mean?

Comment: sit\lie on the grid?

Comment: The line of the interface $\Sigma$ is the line of a grid. At this grid: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IeXuf.png it's the black line in the middle.

Comment: yes you got it!

Comment: When we take an even number of points $N$ then the interface $\Sigma$ will not be on the grid, right? @MichaelMedvinsky $$$$
Are both cases ($N$ odd, $N$ even) right?

Comment: try `for j=(2.^{1:5}+1),linspace(-1,1,j),end`

Comment: Which command should this replace? @MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: neither, it is for you to help you to conclude about your question

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I tried it... So, we see that when we take as $N$ a power of $2$ we don't get $y=0$, right? Does this only happen when $N$ is a power of $2$, or generally when $N$ is even? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Also could you explain me why $g_p$ is a  continuous approximation of the step function ?

Comment: $ g_p$ is continuous, and $$\lim_{M\to\infty} g_p=\text{ step function}$$ also read the description of $g_p$ in the answer

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Could you take a look at my question? http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21563/find-cfl-condition