# Calculation of error

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, numerical-analysis, error-estimation, elliptic-pde

I have written a code in which I find the approximation of the solution of [this elliptic problem](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21316/points-on-the-interface).

I calculated the error using the following part of code:

http://pastebin.com/7b5mmuRW

but I get the following errors for $a=-1, b=1, k_1=k_2=1$ :

```
For N=10:  er = 9.9920e-016
For N=20: er = 2.4425e-015
For N=30: er = 7.1054e-015
For N=40: er = 7.7716e-015
For N=50: er = 1.5765e-014
For N=60: er = 1.6764e-014
For N=70: er = 1.0436e-014
```

But the error should decrease while $N$ increases. 
What have I done wrong at the code above?

**EDIT**:Using this code: http://pastebin.com/crS4vb1t

I get the following results:

> > [rate,Error]=order

rate =

```
0.2221   -2.0880   -0.2637   -2.7620
```

Error =

1.0e-014 *

```
0.0281    0.0241    0.1024    0.1230    0.8342
```

**EDIT 2**:

For $N=4$, $k_1=k_2=1$ the matrix A, with the code that I have written, is the following:

A =

Columns 1 through 14

```
-4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1    -4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1    -4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1    -4     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0    -4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     1    -4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     1    -4     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     1    -4     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0    -4     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1    -4     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1    -4     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1    -4     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0    -4     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1    -4
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Columns 15 through 16

```
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 1     0
 0     1
 0     0
 1     0
-4     1
 1    -4
```

**EDIT**: Here is the log-log graph of the errors in relation to $N$:

[image]

So the errors can't be right. Or am I wrong?

Comment: what you see here is pretty much the machine's error, so it cannot decrease anymore...

Comment: Also, please don't use pastebin for the crucial code, because this question is essentially meaningless once the paste gets deleted (as happened for your other question).

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Why does the error decrease for $N=10$ and $N=20$, then for $N=30$ and $N=40$ it increases, then it decreases and increases alternately?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Did you see my edit?

Comment: @evinda: MichaelMedvinsky already stated the correct answer -- for all practical purposes,1e-15 is zero. So regardless of your $N$, the error is and remains zero. The particular values don't matter -- they're all zero within roundoff.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth So do you mean that all the results are equal to zero? But if so can we find the order of accuracy?

Comment: @evinda yes, I see. Now run the code with new $f$ and post result. You will probably will be able to see the convergence rate better, i.e. if your code is correct.

Comment: also look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513538/can-poisson-equation-be-solved-numerically-in-one-shot/1513561#1513561

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I think the matrix $A$ that I found is of the same form as the one that you calculated at your answer of the other post. I have edited my post...

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky What kind of $f$ should I use so that we see the convergence rate better?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I plotted the loglog- graph of the erros in relation to $N$. So the erros can't be right. Can they?

Comment: try your code with $f=-2\pi^2 \sin\pi x\sin\pi y$, the exact solution is $u=\sin\pi x\sin\pi y$ . Also note that the matrix $A$ should be divided by $h^2$.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I have edited my post by adding the results for this $f$. Now the error is decreasing. But then the rate is $0.1183$. Why?
$$$$
I have multiplied the RHS with h^2: 

`U=A\(h^2*FK);`

Comment: that is fine to multiply it to RHS. also see my answer...

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Using the other function $f$ that Michael Medvinsky proposed, we see that the error is decreasing while $N$ is increasing. Why does this happen for this function and not for the one that I have used above, i.e. $2 ((x^2-1)+(y^2-1))$ ?

Comment: It's because you chose a polynomial function which your method can *exactly* solve regardless of $N$. Let's say you are using quadratic functions. Then think about how you approximate the solution with piecewise quadratic shape functions. If the exact solution happens to be a quadratic function, then your approximation is exact regardless of the mesh size. But if your exact solution is not polynomial or at least has polynomial terms of higher order, then there will be an error, and the error becomes smaller as $N$ becomes larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a many days of discussions, your problems are

1) you choose too simple problem for which you reach the machine zero and therefore cannot observe normal properties
2) perhaps you do not use the boundary values correctly. With the scheme you work the values should be added to the RHS, but since they are zero there is nothing to add. However, one thing to remember, the boundaries points shouldn't be a part of computation.

See the following code, for the two problems (two different sources), one the simple one you worked with and the second one I suggested to solve in comments.

```
for Kind=1:2 % define what problem to solve
    errpre=0;%just to initialize this with something

    for N = 1:7

        %create grid
        n=2^(N+1);
        x=linspace(-1,1,n+2);
        y=linspace(-1,1,n+2);
        h= abs(x(1)-x(2));
        [X,Y]=meshgrid(x(2:end-1),y(2:end-1));

        %create descrete operator
        I = speye(n,n);
        E = sparse(2:n,1:n-1,1,n,n);
        D = E+E'-2*I;
        A = (kron(D,I)+kron(I,D))./(h^2);

        %create RHS and the exact solution
        if Kind==1
            f=2* ((X.^2 - 1) + (Y.^2 - 1));
            ex=(X.^2 - 1) .*(Y.^2 - 1);
        elseif Kind==2
            ex = sin(pi*X).*sin(pi*Y);
            f=-ex*2*pi^2;
        end
        %solve the problem
        ap = (A\f(:));

        %compute the error
        err  = norm(ex(:)-ap(:),inf)/norm(ap(:),inf);

        %print the error and the rate
        fprintf('Kind=%d\t n=%d\t err=%-10.8d\t rate=%-4.2f\n',Kind,n,err,log2(errpre/err));

        %keep the old value for the rate calculation at next step
        errpre=err;

    end
end
```

Run this code to get

```
Kind=1   n=4     err=2.40933816e-16  rate=-Inf
Kind=1   n=8     err=5.69076036e-16  rate=-1.24
Kind=1   n=16    err=8.94357034e-16  rate=-0.65
Kind=1   n=32    err=3.11434148e-15  rate=-1.80
Kind=1   n=64    err=1.11074876e-15  rate=1.49
Kind=1   n=128   err=3.77521199e-15  rate=-1.77
Kind=1   n=256   err=1.42112850e-14  rate=-1.91

Kind=2   n=4     err=1.24859800e-01  rate=-Inf
Kind=2   n=8     err=3.99615153e-02  rate=1.64
Kind=2   n=16    err=1.13319182e-02  rate=1.82
Kind=2   n=32    err=3.01735099e-03  rate=1.91
Kind=2   n=64    err=7.78424525e-04  rate=1.95
Kind=2   n=128   err=1.97680908e-04  rate=1.98
Kind=2   n=256   err=4.98085147e-05  rate=1.99
```

Comment: I see... Thank you for your answer!!! @MichaelMedvinsky
$$$$
When we use $k_1 \neq k_2$ do we use the following exact solution and $f$? 

http://pastebin.com/M1KziNDC
$$$$
I get the following results: http://pastebin.com/kQWQZHyC
$$$$
Isn't it wrong?

Comment: to use $k_1\ne k_2$ you first read carefully my answer to your previous question. As for the exact solution. Unless you have a good book with such problems on your table, it might be difficult to find an exact solution for a singular problem. I would suggest to measure the Cauchy condition of convergence, i.e. take a norm of the difference of the solution on subsequent grids, e.g. $\|u_h-u_{h/2}\|$ where $h$ denote the grid size.

Comment: Since the interval is $[-1,1]$, so it is symmetric, when $N$ is an even number the line $y=0$ isn't on the grid. So we don't have a problem with th interface. Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes, but what happens to derivatives across the interface?

Comment: Can we take points for the derivative from the interface although it is not on the grid?

Comment: think about $u_{n+1}-u_{n}$ with the interface between $n+1$ and $n$,

Comment: Neither $u_{n+1}$ nor $u_n$ will be on the interface. Do you mean that there will be a problem with the graph?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31973/discussion-between-michael-medvinsky-and-evinda).

Comment: To measure the cauchy condition of convergence, so $\|u_h-u_{h/2}\|$, why do we use at the command `u_{h/2}(1:2:end,1:2:end)` , $2$ as the step?

Comment: to match the size of previous step

Comment: I have understood this. But why do we choose these elements of the vector and not for example the $N$ first ones? Do we get like that a better approximation?

Comment: what happens when you refine the grid? it is like you have added a grid node between each existent pair of nodes....i.e. $x_j=x_0+jh$ vs $x_j=x_0+j\frac{h}2$

Comment: Ah I see... :) $$$$
Using the function $f$ that you proposed, we see that the error is decreasing while $N$ is increasing. Why does this happen for this function and not for the one that I have used above,$2((x^2−1)+(y^2−1)) $?

Comment: because it is so simple problem that you immediately reach the machine zero, which cannot be bettered....the error is grows because of round-off error http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RoundoffError.html

Comment: So because of the fact that the approximation is almost the same as the exact solution, right?

Comment: yes, you got it

Comment: Could you take a look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928542/series-in-matlab

Comment: If we have the equation $u_t+2 u_x=0$ and implement the upwind-method I get these values for the order of accuracy: $$$$
p1 = -129.6068 -112.0078 -105.0702
$$$$
I use this code: http://pastebin.com/PYUkkkBH $$$$
Is it wrong?

Comment: open new question

Comment: Could you take a look at my question? http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/behaviour-of-approximation